# Как вывести результаты GridSearchCV для классификатора sklearn.svm.SVC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

Задача - подгрузить текстовую выборку, нормализовать её в числовую форму, подбор параметра сети.

Имею:

```
import sklearn
from sklearn import svm, datasets
newsgroups = datasets.fetch_20newsgroups(subset='all', categories=['alt.atheism', 'sci.space'])
X=newsgroups.data  #данные 
y=newsgroups.target #индексы
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer as tfv
vector = tfv()  # TF-IDF
data_X = vector.fit_transform(X)  #тестовая выборка
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
grid = {'C': np.power(10.0, np.arange(-5, 6))} #указание параметров словаря
cv = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=241)  #конструктор разбиений
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
clf = sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear', random_state=241)  #классификатор
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv) #подбор параметров
gs.fit(data_X, y)
```

Хочу получить:

```
for a in gs.grid_scores_:
    a.mean_validation_score # оценка качества по кросс-валидации
    a.parameters # значения параметров
```

Но это для старой версии. Для последней ***как-то так***:

```
gs.best_estimator_
gs.best_params_
gs.best_score_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удобнее всего будет преобразовать `gs.cv_results_` (результат настройки сети параметров) в Pandas.DataFrame.

Пример:

```
grid = {
    'C': np.power(10.0, np.arange(-1, 2)),
    'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear'],
} 
gs = GridSearchCV(clf, grid, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, 
                  n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, return_train_score=True) #подбор параметров
gs.fit(data_X, y)
```

Сетка параметров:

```
In [22]: grid
Out[22]: {'C': array([ 0.1,  1. , 10. ]), 'kernel': ['rbf', 'linear']}
```

Создаем DataFrame из `gs.cv_results_`:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(gs.cv_results_)
```

Получилось:

```
In [19]: res
Out[19]:
   mean_fit_time  std_fit_time  mean_score_time  std_score_time  ... split3_train_score split4_train_score mean_train_score  std_train_score
0       3.368227      0.116977         0.814210        0.058673  ...           0.565430           0.549335         0.552632         0.007027
1       2.908841      0.158428         0.727257        0.025806  ...           0.961512           0.967810         0.964305         0.004109
2       3.504162      0.136986         0.799417        0.056557  ...           0.565430           0.549335         0.552632         0.007027
3       1.824952      0.080142         0.426784        0.016244  ...           0.999300           1.000000         0.999720         0.000343
4       3.601515      0.124061         0.748441        0.045909  ...           0.565430           0.549335         0.552632         0.007027
5       1.842038      0.092328         0.407099        0.009595  ...           1.000000           1.000000         1.000000         0.000000

[6 rows x 22 columns]

In [20]: res.columns
Out[20]:
Index(['mean_fit_time', 'std_fit_time', 'mean_score_time', 'std_score_time', 'param_C', 'param_kernel', 'params',
       'split0_test_score', 'split1_test_score', 'split2_test_score', 'split3_test_score', 'split4_test_score',
       'mean_test_score', 'std_test_score', 'rank_test_score', 'split0_train_score', 'split1_train_score',
       'split2_train_score', 'split3_train_score', 'split4_train_score', 'mean_train_score', 'std_train_score'],
      dtype='object')
```

Выберем только интересующие нас столбцы:

```
In [21]: res.filter(regex='^(?:mean|param)')
Out[21]:
   mean_fit_time  mean_score_time param_C param_kernel                           params  mean_test_score  mean_train_score
0       3.368227         0.814210     0.1          rbf      {'C': 0.1, 'kernel': 'rbf'}         0.552632          0.552632
1       2.908841         0.727257     0.1       linear   {'C': 0.1, 'kernel': 'linear'}         0.950168          0.964305
2       3.504162         0.799417       1          rbf      {'C': 1.0, 'kernel': 'rbf'}         0.552632          0.552632
3       1.824952         0.426784       1       linear   {'C': 1.0, 'kernel': 'linear'}         0.993281          0.999720
4       3.601515         0.748441      10          rbf     {'C': 10.0, 'kernel': 'rbf'}         0.552632          0.552632
5       1.842038         0.407099      10       linear  {'C': 10.0, 'kernel': 'linear'}         0.993281          1.000000
```